# C (gnu11): Nested function segfaults

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, nested-function

I use C11 with the gnu extensions (`--std=gnu11`). Given the following code with nested functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (int_f)();

void print_f_res(int_f f) {
    printf("f() = %d\n", f());
}

void rr(int n) {
    int id() {
        return n;
    }

    if (n > 0) {
        rr(n - 1);
    }

    print_f_res(&id);
}


int main() {
    rr(3);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a segfault if I run it:

```sh
➜  /tmp/test gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror test.c --std=gnu11 -O0 -g
➜  /tmp/test ./a.out
[1]    11713 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

If I run it with valgrind it works:

```sh
➜  /tmp/test valgrind ./a.out

==11491== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11491== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11491== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11491== Command: ./a.out
==11491==
==11491== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
f() = 0
f() = 1
f() = 2
f() = 3
==11491==
==11491== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11491==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11491==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 512 bytes allocated
==11491==
==11491== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11491==
==11491== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11491== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
➜  /tmp/test
```

gcc version:

```sh
➜  /tmp/test gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Do I use nested functions wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: Since you already compile your code with debugging enabled, run it with `gdb` and if you can't figure it out, add the debugger output to your question.

Comment: Why define a function in another function?  In your case, you can just use `printf` directly, right?

Comment: @FiddlingBits true, but this is just a minimal "working" example

Comment: @KevinMeier Got you.  That makes sense.

Comment: I can't reproduce.

Comment: Can't reproduce. https://ideone.com/gHn5oM

Comment: Weird :/... Thanks for testing it!

Comment: I will focus on this `error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block` in valgrind

Comment: Something is wrong with your system. Will simple "hello world" compiled the same way work?

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>
int main(){printf("hello world!\n");}` works perfect. Actually, I'm working on several C projects and they all work well with my system. But they do not use nested functions.

Comment: Then try some other compiler.. There is a chance that you have hit some compiler bug.

Comment: Solution found: I'm using WSL and WSL does not support this features: See https://nullprogram.com/blog/2019/11/15/ and https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/286

Comment: @KevinMeier Please turn you comment into an answer and accept it.

Comment: Again, one more on the "WSL is defect by design" counter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found:

I'm using WSL and WSL does not support this features: See https://nullprogram.com/blog/2019/11/15/ and https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/286